# Parsing XML with default namespace using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I have the following format which i need to get my XML format in using SSMS

```
<ESBTimecardLoad xmlns="http://test.com/schemas">
      <Initialize xmlns="http://test.com/schemas">
            <Add>
                  <TimeCard>
                        <Attributes>
                              <Timekeeper AliasField="Number">C1235</Timekeeper>
                              <WorkDate>5/11/2018</WorkDate>
                              <WorkHrs>1.50</WorkHrs>
                              <Matter AliasField="Number">04420.3004</Matter>
                              <WorkType>Admin</WorkType>
                              <Phase AliasField="Code">rty</Phase>
                              <Task AliasField="Code">QEW</Task>
                              <Activity AliasField="Code">TTT</Activity>                  
                        </Attributes>
                  </TimeCardPending>
            </Add>
            <Add>
                  <TimeCardPending>
                        <Attributes>
                              <Timekeeper AliasField="Number">C888888</Timekeeper>
                              <WorkDate>7/6/2017</WorkDate>
                              <WorkHrs>0.25</WorkHrs>
                              <Matter AliasField="Number">01594.1009</Matter>
                              <WorkType>Enterprise</WorkType>
                              <Phase AliasField="Code">P3</Phase>
                              <Task AliasField="Code">QWE</Task>
                              <Activity AliasField="Code">YYY</Activity>
                        </Attributes>
                  </TimeCardPending>
            </Add>
</Start>
</TimecardLoad>
```

I have the following query to get the XML. Note that the Add, Timecard and attributes are repeated for each record. Would it be possible to group the 3 tags together for each record? I am having trouble to create the repeating groupings and the Aliasfield section for each record.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://Test.com/schemas') 
   SELECT
       CAST ((SELECT TOP 2 
                  [Team] "Timekeeper", 
                  [Date] "WorkDate",
                  [WorkHrs],
                  [Matter] "Matter",
                  [WorkType] "WorkType",
                  [Phase], [task],
                  [Activity], [Notes] AS Narrative    
              FROM
                  view_review     
              FOR XML PATH('Attributes'), ROOT('Initialize')) AS XML)
FOR XML PATH('TimeCardLoad'), ELEMENTS
```

This is my result:

```
<ESBTimeCardLoad xmlns="http://test.com/schemas">
  <Initialize xmlns="http://test.com/schemas">
    <Attributes>
      <Timekeeper>TEster, Monica</Timekeeper>
      <WorkDate>05/25/15</WorkDate>
      <WorkHrs>10.00</WorkHrs>
      <Phase>P3</Phase>
      <task>P3_Fsol</task>
      <Activity>SETUPS3</Activity>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes>
      <Timekeeper>Mob, JOhn</Timekeeper>
      <WorkDate>05/27/15</WorkDate>
      <WorkHrs>8.00</WorkHrs>
      <Phase>P3</Phase>
      <task>P3_Fsol</task>
      <Activity>SETUPS3</Activity>
    </Attributes>
  </Initialize>
</ESBTimeCardLoad>
```

In which way should I change the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML you show us as *format which i need to get my XML* is not well-formed in many ways:

- You open with `<ESBTimecardLoad><Initialize>` but you end with `</Start></TimecardLoad>`
- Within first `<Add>` you open with `<TimeCard>`, but you end with `<TimeCardPending>`
- you should not use a culture dependant format for your dates. `5/11/2018` might be taken as *5th of November* or the *11th of May*...

The following will show the principles with some of your columns. Check it out.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, TimeKeeper VARCHAR(100),WorkDate DATE, WorkHrs DECIMAL(6,2), Matter VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('C1235','2018-11-05',1.5,04420.3004)
,('C8888','2017-06-07',0.25,01594.1009);

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://Test.com/schemas') 
SELECT
(
    SELECT 'Number' AS [TimeCardPending/Attributes/Timekeeper/@AliasField]
          ,TimeKeeper AS [TimeCardPending/Attributes/Timekeeper]
          ,WorkHrs AS [TimeCardPending/Attributes/WorkHrs]
          ,'Number' AS [TimeCardPending/Attributes/Matter/@AliasField]
          ,Matter AS [TimeCardPending/Attributes/Matter]
          --and so on
    FROM @tbl t
    FOR XML PATH('Add'),ROOT('Initialize'),TYPE
) AS [*]
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('ESBTimecardLoad');
```

the result

```
<ESBTimecardLoad xmlns="http://Test.com/schemas">
  <Initialize xmlns="http://Test.com/schemas">
    <Add>
      <TimeCardPending>
        <Attributes>
          <Timekeeper AliasField="Number">C1235</Timekeeper>
          <WorkHrs>1.50</WorkHrs>
          <Matter AliasField="Number">4420.3004</Matter>
        </Attributes>
      </TimeCardPending>
    </Add>
    <Add>
      <TimeCardPending>
        <Attributes>
          <Timekeeper AliasField="Number">C8888</Timekeeper>
          <WorkHrs>0.25</WorkHrs>
          <Matter AliasField="Number">1594.1009</Matter>
        </Attributes>
      </TimeCardPending>
    </Add>
  </Initialize>
</ESBTimecardLoad>
```